# A question regarding continuous curves.

Tags: analysis

Say $f:\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a continuous map. Now take the fibre of $a\in\Bbb{R}$, which is $f^{-1}(a)$. Will it always be a continuous curve in $\Bbb{R^2}$?

I tried constructing examples. Clearly $(x,y)\to x^2+y^2$ satisfies this condition, as $f^{-1}(a)$ is a circle for every $a\in\Bbb{R}$. However, I don't know how to prove this for the general case.

Comment: It is easy to make a fibre that consists of a finite number of points, or curves.

Comment: For $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$, the fibre $f^{-1}(0)$ is a single point and $f^{-1}(a)$ for $a < 0$ is the empty set.

Comment: @JimmyK4542- Can you map $(0,1)$ to an empty set? Is such a mapping defined?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x,y)=xy$ and think about $f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @Anurag- How do you prove that the union of the X-Y axes is not a curve?

Answer (score 0):

Look at $f(x,y)=x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)^2+y^2$. Then $f^{-1}(0)$ consists of three points.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome. One can play more elaborate versions of the same game.